# Match ALT key in Java with ActionMap

Tags: java

I have a JTextArea and I want to trigger a message when ALT key is pressed.
This is the code that doesn't matches ALT and I don't know why.

```
JTextArea jtf1 = new JTextArea();
jtf1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(18, 0), "handleGS");
jtf1.getActionMap().put("handleGS", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        System.err.println("Found");
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("alt")` instead?

Comment: Yes I tried but is not working, then I thought that ALT(18) should be the second argument of  getKeyStroke but I don't know how can I match only alt without other key presses.

Comment: I don't remember exactly how it works but maybe adding that handler to `jtf1` needs `jtf1` to be focused. Did you try focusing it before pressing the alt key? Did it work?

Comment: It's focused, I click inside the JTextArea and after that I hit ALT.

Comment: Other keys are working, as I tested only ALT, CTRL and SHIFT have this problem. But these are exactly the keys I need to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `ALT` key is a mask, so you have to use it as modifier.

I got it working this way:

```
JTextArea jtf1 = new JTextArea();
jtf1.getInputMap().put(
  KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK), 
  "handleGS"
);
jtf1.getActionMap().put("handleGS", new AbstractAction() {
  public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    System.err.println("Found");
  }
});
```